# Find monitor size and it's company

Tags: vb6

How can i find the monitor size(not pixel, actual physical size) and it's company(manufacturer) by using vb6 code. I saw some links which give screen size using WMI(WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams and WmiMonitorID) and some other by using some registry, but nothing worked for me. Can anyone tell me how it can be done by using vb6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article about it : [here](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/)

He describes the same steps as you tried, which failed, and came up with something else in the end.
I don't know if it works for you, but it seems the most promising I could find.